# How to delete JPG files, but only if the matching RAW file exists?

Tags: bash, file-extension

On debian terminal, I try to delete all .jpg of a folder and subfolder if .cr2 exist on the same folder.

Assumes they have the same name.
123.jpg
123.cr2

I know how to delete all .jpg with find command.

```
find {PATH} -type f -name '*.jpg' -delete
```

but how can I add a condition (if .cr2 exist)

I found this [10y topics](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16401/how-to-delete-jpg-files-but-only-if-the-matching-raw-file-exists#16413) but it's for windows and python

Comment: Remarkably, I was unable to find a duplicate for this, even though it seems like a FAQ. Thanks for filling a gap in the knowledge base!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
shopt -s globstar
for i in /path/**.jpg
do
RAW=${i%.jpg}.cr2
if [ -f "$RAW" ]
then rm "$i"
fi
done
```

If you are fan of oneliners you can convert the script to something like:

```
shopt -s globstar; for i in /path/**.jpg; do [ -f "${i%.jpg}.cr2" ] && rm "$i"; done
```

Comment: The `**` glob is supported by most modern shells, but it's not a POSIX feature. Some sites turn it off by default so you will then have to enable it separately. In Bash, `shopt -s globstar`

Comment: @tripleee, thank you, will update the script

Comment: Just FYI, you could replace your 3-line `if-then-fi` with `[ -f "$RAW" ] && rm "$i"`

Comment: @MarkSetchell, correct, but I prefer old school  way ":)

Comment: Cool - you already have my vote

Comment: @MarkSetchell, thank you. Probably the code can be shorten even more: `[ -f "${i%.jpg}.cr2" ] && rm "$i"`

Comment: Indeed, and if you put semi-colons in too, before `do` and `done`, it can be a one-liner

Comment: Thank you very much everyone, it works! Seems not work for subfolder.

Could you explain, waht's "**"?

Comment: `**` mean exactly to search in current and subdirectories. As explained above in comments this is not standard feature. So it need to be activated (if shell support it)